# QTP 11.0 not recording actions in IE 11

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, qtp, action-recording

I am trying to do simple recording of actions in Web-page using HP QTP 11.0. QTP is ran under admin user.

The settings used are:

- `Record and Run Settings` > `Web` > `Open the following address when a record or run session begins`: http://www.google.com/
- `Tools` > `Options` > `Web` > `Advanced` checkbox `Enable Web Support for Microsoft Windows Explorer` tried both selected and not
- `Tools` > `Web Event Recording Configuration` set to `High`

Also "played" with `Tools` > `Object Identification` in dropdown `Environment` select `Web` and added `visible` to `Mandatory Properties` of `WebEdit`, `WebCheckbox` etc. all web-starting stuff.

When I press `Record` browser is opened on the specified Google page, but all the actions I do are not recorded.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Also tried downgrading to IE 10, 9 the result is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a support contract and an account for the HP Software Support Online site, you can find the Product Availability Matrices for QTP/UFT in the given link [here](https://softwaresupport.hp.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM438391)

According to HP Documentation, IE 11 is not supported for QTP 11.0.
The first version to support IE 11 on Windows 8  is UFT 12. The first version to support IE 11 on Windows 7 SP1 is also UFT 12.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this as a comment, but it's too long to post it as such:

According to a post on [Source: Forum post on sqaforums](http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/hp-unified-functional-testing-uft-mercury-quicktest-pro-qtp/151497-qtp-11-support-ie-11-a.html) which points to the product matrix, IE11 is not supported by QTP 11:

> Following is the support matrix:
>
> - QTP 11 supports only IE 9.
> - QTP 11.5 supports only IE 9.
> - QTP 11.53 supports IE 10.
> - QTP 12 supports IE 11.

Answer (score -1):

Working with IE11 needs some patches to be installed than only you can work with IE11, without patches you can work on IE8, even IE9 require list of patches.

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit you answer and provide more details than "require some patches"

Comment: I have to agree with bish, knowing what patches are necessary would make this answer much better.